# Increasing the stack limit in OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos

I am looking for a way to (not necessarily permanently) increase the stack size available to terminal applications in OS X 10.10.

I know there are a lot of questions related to changing environment variables, including stack limit, on the internet and here in particular (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385934/setting-environment-variables-via-launchd-conf-no-longer-works-in-os-x-yosemite)) but none of the proposed solutions I have found seems to work for me.

The most I get out of `launchctl` is using `sudo launchctl limit stack 67104768 67104768` where 67104768 is the default hard limit. Other `launchctl` commands with higher limits seem to have no effect.

Then there is `sysctl`, but its man pages report `kern.stack_size` as unchangeable.

I hope I have not overlooked any solutions that have already been proposed somewhere; any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I would like to increase the stack limit to work around what seems to be a bug in ocamlopt, the OCaml native compiler, that stack-overflows processing a particular (sensible) program; I can't seem to find the bug report right now.

Comment: Are you explicitly asking how to increase Yosemite's stack limit?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, if that wasn't clear from the text.

Comment: I found a question at http://superuser.com/questions/836883/increasing-yosemite-maxfile-limit-for-application that might help you... In the first answer, it shows a maxfiles limit. Perhaps change it to stack limit and save as `limit.stack.plist` into launchDaemons?

Comment: Thanks! I just tried that, but no luck.

Comment: Ok. And did you actually find the limit file? If it is not there. I will spend time looking for it and fixing the problem. And configuring that plist I instructed earlier.

Comment: The file wasn't there before, so I created it and changed the file permissions in the way as described in the post, adapting for 'stack'. That didn't seem to work.

Comment: Are you still interested in the solution for this? If so might you be able to edit what downside you're seeing with the stack defaults?  is it one specific programs causing an issue?

Comment: Yes, I would still be interested in a solution. Thanks, made the edit. There could indeed also be some ocamlopt-specific thing I could try out that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 6):

One way to increase the stack size is to use `ulimit`:

```
shell> ulimit -s new_size_in_kb
```

Just keep in mind that there seems to be a hard limit on how big the stack can be on OSX and that limit appears to be 65532 kb:

```
shell> ulimit -s 65533
ulimit: value exceeds hard limit
shell> ulimit -s 65532
shell> ulimit -a | grep stack
-s: stack size (kbytes)             65532
```

Also `ulimit -s` is temporary and resets once the terminal session ends.

If you want to make sure that the stack is increased for every terminal session, you could put the `ulimit -s` command in your .zshrc or equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for that! Unfortunately in this particular case I need to increase the stack size beyond OSX's hard limit and I was hoping to find a solution that increases this limit.

Comment: Yeah: also a ```ulimit -s unlimited``` seems to be limited to 65532 Kb: ```ulimit -a | grep stack``` gives ```-s: stack size (kbytes)             65532```